# Multiple quotation table in a single qweb report in ODOO

Tags: odoo-10, odoo-9, qweb, odoo-11, odoo-view

I am trying to make qweb report that takes multiple quotations of the same customer to be printed in a single paper format in odoo 10. I have just started learning odoo and I want to customize sale_report_templates.xml so please help me with some examples. Thanks

Comment: You can achieve that by selecting many quotations of the same customer in list view and click on the print button.

Comment: This way will give you every selected quotation in a separate paper but in the same pdf

Comment: `in a single report` as you asked.You need to edit your question and add more details.

Comment: I am sorry about that